# The procedure entry point ... renderSynchronous@QRenderAspectPrivate@Qt3DRender ... could not be located in the dynamic link library ... *.dll

Tags: qt, deployment, dependencies

I'm using `windeployqt.exe` to deploy my application like this:

```
PS C:\Users\me\Documents\deploy-win10-milestone-5-stripped-trytofix> C:\Qt\Qt5.11.2\5.11.2\msvc2017_64\bin\windeployqt.exe .\qt3dsceneeditor.dll
C:\Users\me\Documents\deploy-win10-milestone-5-stripped-trytofix\qt3dsceneeditor.dll 64 bit, release executable [QML]
Adding Qt5Svg for qsvgicon.dll
Adding Qt53DAnimation for assimpsceneimport.dll
Direct dependencies: Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Qml Qt5Quick Qt5Widgets Qt53DCore Qt53DRender Qt53DInput Qt53DExtras
All dependencies   : Qt5Concurrent Qt5Core Qt5Gamepad Qt5Gui Qt5Network Qt5Qml Qt5Quick Qt5Widgets Qt53DCore Qt53DRender Qt53DInput Qt53DExtras
To be deployed     : Qt5Concurrent Qt5Core Qt5Gamepad Qt5Gui Qt5Network Qt5Qml Qt5Quick Qt5Svg Qt5Widgets Qt53DCore Qt53DRender Qt53DInput Qt53DAnimation Qt53DExtras
Warning: Cannot find Visual Studio installation directory, VCINSTALLDIR is not set.
Updating Qt53DLogic.dll.
Updating Qt5Concurrent.dll.
Updating Qt5Core.dll.
Updating Qt5Gamepad.dll.
Updating Qt5Gui.dll.
Updating Qt5Network.dll.
Updating Qt5Qml.dll.
Updating Qt5Quick.dll.
Updating Qt5Svg.dll.
Updating Qt5Widgets.dll.
Updating Qt53DCore.dll.
Updating Qt53DRender.dll.
Updating Qt53DInput.dll.
Updating Qt53DAnimation.dll.
Updating Qt53DExtras.dll.
Updating libGLESV2.dll.
Updating libEGL.dll.
Updating D3Dcompiler_47.dll.
Updating opengl32sw.dll.
Patching Qt5Core.dll...
Creating directory C:/Users/me/Documents/deploy-win10-milestone-5-stripped-trytofix/bearer.
Updating qgenericbearer.dll.
Creating directory C:/Users/me/Documents/deploy-win10-milestone-5-stripped-trytofix/gamepads.
Updating xinputgamepad.dll.
Creating directory C:/Users/me/Documents/deploy-win10-milestone-5-stripped-trytofix/geometryloaders.
Updating defaultgeometryloader.dll.
Updating gltfgeometryloader.dll.
Creating directory C:/Users/me/Documents/deploy-win10-milestone-5-stripped-trytofix/iconengines.
Updating qsvgicon.dll.
Creating directory C:/Users/me/Documents/deploy-win10-milestone-5-stripped-trytofix/imageformats.
Updating qgif.dll.
Updating qicns.dll.
Updating qico.dll.
Updating qjpeg.dll.
Updating qsvg.dll.
Updating qtga.dll.
Updating qtiff.dll.
Updating qwbmp.dll.
Updating qwebp.dll.
Creating directory C:/Users/me/Documents/deploy-win10-milestone-5-stripped-trytofix/platforminputcontexts.
Updating qtvirtualkeyboardplugin.dll.
Creating directory C:/Users/me/Documents/deploy-win10-milestone-5-stripped-trytofix/platforms.
Updating qwindows.dll.
Creating directory C:/Users/me/Documents/deploy-win10-milestone-5-stripped-trytofix/qmltooling.
Updating qmldbg_debugger.dll.
Updating qmldbg_inspector.dll.
Updating qmldbg_local.dll.
Updating qmldbg_messages.dll.
Updating qmldbg_native.dll.
Updating qmldbg_nativedebugger.dll.
Updating qmldbg_profiler.dll.
Updating qmldbg_quickprofiler.dll.
Updating qmldbg_server.dll.
Updating qmldbg_tcp.dll.
Creating directory C:/Users/me/Documents/deploy-win10-milestone-5-stripped-trytofix/renderplugins.
Updating scene2d.dll.
Creating directory C:/Users/me/Documents/deploy-win10-milestone-5-stripped-trytofix/scenegraph.
Updating qsgd3d12backend.dll.
Creating directory C:/Users/me/Documents/deploy-win10-milestone-5-stripped-trytofix/sceneparsers.
Updating assimpsceneimport.dll.
Updating gltfsceneexport.dll.
Updating gltfsceneimport.dll.
Creating C:\Users\me\Documents\deploy-win10-milestone-5-stripped-trytofix\translations...
Creating qt_ar.qm...
Creating qt_bg.qm...
Creating qt_ca.qm...
Creating qt_cs.qm...
Creating qt_da.qm...
Creating qt_de.qm...
Creating qt_en.qm...
Creating qt_es.qm...
Creating qt_fi.qm...
Creating qt_fr.qm...
Creating qt_gd.qm...
Creating qt_he.qm...
Creating qt_hu.qm...
Creating qt_it.qm...
Creating qt_ja.qm...
Creating qt_ko.qm...
Creating qt_lv.qm...
Creating qt_pl.qm...
Creating qt_ru.qm...
Creating qt_sk.qm...
Creating qt_uk.qm...
PS C:\Users\me\Documents\deploy-win10-milestone-5-stripped-trytofix>
```

But when I run my application, I receive the following error:

> The procedure entry point ... renderSynchronous@QRenderAspectPrivate@Qt3DRender ... could not be located in the dynamic link library ... qt3dsceneeditor.dll

Why is this error received? Isn't `windeployqt.exe` supposed to detect and copy over all the dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to **version mis-match**. I was running the command like this:

```
> C:\Qt\Qt5.11.2\5.11.2\msvc2017_64\bin\windeployqt.exe .\qt3dsceneeditor.dll
```

My application is built with Qt 5.11.2, but for some reason the `C:\Qt\Qt5.11.2\5.11.2\msvc2017_64\bin\windeployqt.exe` executable was copying the DLLs from Qt 5.9.4 directory! I **renamed** Qt 5.9.4 folder and ran the command again and the error got resolved.